# Laravel multiple levels relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I am stuck on a problem on relationships
this is my database :

```
users table:
id
```

```
participants table:
user_id
conversation_id
```

```
conversations table:
name
```

In my user class

```
    public function participants() {
        return $this->hasMany(Participant::class);
    }

    public function conversations() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Conversation::class, Participant::class);
    }
```

But i have an error when I try to access conversations.

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'conversations.participant_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `conversations`.*, `participants`.`user_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `conversations` inner join `participants` on `participants`.`id` = `conversations`.`participant_id` where `participants`.`user_id` = 1)
```

I tried this

```
    public function conversations() {
        return $this->hasMany(Participant::class)->with('conversation');
    }
```

But the result is not really fine and I m not sur that's the good way to do it !

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a hasManyThrough relationship structure, neither a hasMany

That's a belongsToMany relationship, but instead of you having a conversation_user table, you named it participants try this:

```
public function conversations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Conversation::class, 'participants');
}
```

The second parameter `'participants'`, is for overriding the expected table name, which, would be `'conversation_user'`. I recommend reading more about it on the docs. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

BTW, you are missing an id on the conversations table, but I suppose you have it because you have conversation_id on participants.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official Laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through);

> Typical Eloquent foreign key conventions will be used when performing the relationship's queries. If you would like to customize the keys of the relationship, you may pass them as the third and fourth arguments to the hasManyThrough method. The third argument is the name of the foreign key on the intermediate model. The fourth argument is the name of the foreign key on the final model. The fifth argument is the local key, while the sixth argument is the local key of the intermediate model:

You need to customize your `conversations` method according to your foreign keys.